# paypal phonegap integration for android

Tags: cordova, paypal

I have two different Uber-like android phonegap apps, one client app and other driver app. Client can call a driver for ride from his app. The minimum charge is 20$ for 10 km and 3$ for each extra km (more than 10 km). Client will enter credit card credentials while signing and can only take ride after logged in. When ride is complete, driver will enter the total distance covered. My question is, how can I use paypal to charge user from driver app? Any tutorial on phonegap SDK that will address my need? Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What would probably work best would be to authorize the user's credit card, then capture the funds when the driver enters mileage. The process would look like this

1. User creates account/logs in
2. User enters a credit card and you authorize, say, $100
3. Users takes ride
4. Driver enters mileage
5. You calculate final fees and capture whatever funds you need
6. You send user a receipt in their app/email/etc.

I would use AJAX from within Cordova to do your calls.